# Type T | null is not assignable to type string | null. How come?

Tags: angular

I have a parent component, that uses a child component with an input binding like so:

```
// parent.component.html
<my-child [myBinding]="myObserVable$ | async"></my-child>
```

and its controller:

```
// parent.component.ts
public myObservable$ = new Subject<string>();

private someFunctions(event: string) {
    this.myObservable$.next(event);
}
```

The child component's controller:

```
// my-child.component.ts
@Input()
set myBinding(value: string | null) {
    // ...
}
```

Everything works fine. The observable is of type string and the async pipe (can) add a null to it, but IntellJ underlines `"myObservable$ | async"` redly and shows up `Type T | null is not assignable to type string | null` on hovering.
[image]

Am I doing anything wrong and can I modify the code in order to fix the issue?

Comment: This code doesn't seem to reproduce the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-raboaa?file=src/app/app.component.ts, perhaps you need to add more? Could just be your linter, maybe more info on what IDE / linter you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaring the type of myObservable$ fixed the red underline.
So I changed

```
// parent.component.ts
public myObservable$ = new Subject<string>();
```

to

```
// parent.component.ts
public myObservable$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
```

and the error linting gone byebye:

[image]